# How to randomly choose an element from a list and then use a simple formula to change this value (and doing it in a for-loop)?

Tags: python, physics

I am doing an assignment to generate particles inside a box (two-dimensional). Now, these particles should move inside the box, so the change in energy can be calculated. The algorithm should just change the position of one particle at a time, and then calculate the velocity. That way it's possible to calculate the kinetic energy.
Maybe it's easier to just include the description of the algorithm (Monte Carlo):

[image]

My problem or question is that I want to choose one of the elements in a list, make that element/position change according to:

**Method for move**
[image]

If I can do that, then the velocity can be found by taking the difference in position and dividing it by time. So I want a for-loop to go randomly through all the positions and calculate the energy. Now I am only able to calculate the velocity for the same particle. Here is my code:

```
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

r_1=random.uniform(0,1)
r_2=random.uniform(0,1)

N=20
LX=10
LY=10
a=1
b=0.5
dt=0.01
x=np.zeros(N)
y=np.zeros(N)
vx=np.zeros(N)
vy=np.zeros(N)


for i in range(N):
    x[i]=random.uniform(0,LX)
    y[i]=random.uniform(0,LY)

l=random.choice(range(len(x)))

for l in range(N):
    l=random.choice(range(len(x)))
    x_initial=x[l]
    #k=random.choice(range(len(y)))
    x[l]=x[l]+(r_1-0.5)*b
    x_final=x[l]
    vx[l]=(x_final-x_initial)/dt
    
print(vx)
```

Comment: ```random.choice``` selects a random item from a list.

Comment: I don't understand where is your problem? your algorithm seems to do what you want

Comment: I could suggest you to use one matrix to x,y position with shape `Nx2` and same for velocities (you can modify xpos and ypos at same time). Also I think you need to define the `r_1,r_2` inside the the for loop so it changes at every particle.

Comment: Look like the code is doing what you are asking..

Comment: `random.choice(range(len(x)))` is just a more expensive way of saying `random.randint(0,len(x)-1)`.